# Python: Selenium Driver: Find elements that have a "text-size" greater than "X"

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

*Hi Community,
could You please assist me with following issue? Any help is highly appreciated*!

I am looking for elements in webpages that have a text-size that is greater than "X" (any given threshold). This is basically what I am trying to achieve:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@style,"text-size" > X)]')
```

However, I am not able to make this run properly. Moreover, extracting every element on the webpage and then looping through each element's properties and compare the text-size to "X" appears to be very inefficient and goes beyond my time constraints.

*Could You please help me? Thank You all in advance!*

Comment: `//*[contains(@style, 'text-size') and number(replace(@style,'text-size:\s*([0-9]+)(;|\s|$)', '$1', 'is')) &gt; 6]` ---- hope you are using XPath ver >= 2.0;

Comment: @Cylian: Thanks for your response! Could please explain shortly where I have to plug in the variable (i.e. "X") that the values are compared with? Thanks in advance (I am pretty new to programming, this one appear to be too complicated for me)

Comment: I believe that you meant to say font-size css property instead of text-size. If possible the could you please share the URL of application that could help me to understand exactly what kind of elements are the on the page and what your requirement is.

Comment: @UnknownBeast: Thanks a lot for Your interest in my issue - gladly, the question was already answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work since you're testing `X` inside the `contains` function, and you compare `X` to a string.

```
//*[contains(@style,"text-size" > X)]
```

Assuming you have the following data :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTMLFont size</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-size:30px;">foo</h1>
<p style="text-size:18px;">bar</p>
<div style="text-size:5px;">foobar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To select elements whit a specific size attribute (greater than `X` for example), you can use the following `XPath 1.0` expressions. Select element with a `text-size > 20` :

```
//*[contains(@style,"text-size")][substring-before(substring-after(@style,"size:"),"px")>20]
```

Select elements with a text-size in the range [5:20] :

```
//*[contains(@style,"text-size")][substring-before(substring-after(@style,"size:"),"px")>4 and substring-before(substring-after(@style,"size:"),"px")<21]
```

Side notes :

- You have to modify these expressions a little bit if the `style` attributes you're dealing with are not exactly the same.
- If you don't want to hardcode `X` value directly in the XPath, you can pass it as a variable in your XPath expression (`+ X +`).

Code :

```
X= 20
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@style,"text-size")][substring-before(substring-after(@style,"size:"),"px")>" + X + "]')
```

Comment: Your amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot, Your answer just saved me at least a couple of days!